# Flask- these two inputs are doing the same function

Tags: python, flask

I want the de request.form.get('Stay') to keep me in the same index and I want request.form.get("Deal") to send me to the deal route and they both send me to the deal route

```
@app.route('/', methods=['POST', "GET"])
def home():
    if request.method == "POST":
        if request.form.get("Stay"):
            return redirect(url_for('home'))
    if request.method == "POST":
        if request.form.get("Deal"):
            return redirect(url_for('deal'))
    return render_template("index.html", year=year)


@app.route('/deal', methods=['POST'])
def deal():
    if len(main.player_hand) == 0:
        main.start()
        main.get_current_score(main.player_hand)
        return render_template("index.html", year=year, player=main.player_hand, dealer=main.dealer_hand[1:],
                               score_d=main.get_dealer_starting_value(main.dealer_hand),
                               score_p=main.get_current_score(main.player_hand))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out ! =)

```
 <form action="/" method="Post" >
 <input class="deal_button" type="submit" value="{{ button }}" name="Deal"/>
<input class="hit_button" type="submit" value="Hit" name="Hit_home"/>
<input class="stay_button" type="submit" value="Stay" name="Stay_home"/>
```

the problem was the buttons names were the same and the action was not set to the correct path. Silly mistake but now I understand it better